# Copy of a Slice from a DataFrame issue while running the script in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to apply multiple user-defined functions to a column of a dataframe one by one.
This is the error it is giving me when I ran it in Django env.

```
(.py3env) [root@---------]# python report_feedback_attribute.py runserver
feedback_attribute.py:89: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  data1['feedback_text'] = data1['feedback_text'].apply(clean_text)  # the feedback_text column has been cleaned
feedback_attribute.py:93: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  data1['feedback_text'] = data1['feedback_text'].astype(str)
feedback_attribute.py:103: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  data1['feedback_text'] = data1['feedback_text'].apply(lambda x: tokenizer.tokenize(x.lower()))
```

It is returning an empty dictionary.

```
{'count': []}
```

I have already tried creating a copy of my dataframe and then working on it. Still no result.

I have also tried applying .loc in this way:

```
data1.loc[:, 'feedback_text'] = data1['feedback_text'].apply(clean_text)
```

(I did this change for every function that I defined and applied on the dataframe).

I also tried creating a new column every time a function was applied to the previous column of a dataframe.

Still no results. Please help.

Edit:

This is data1 (just a sample):
[image]

Comment: How was `data1` defined? i.e., `data1 = ...`

Comment: data1 is a DataFrame with three columns 'feedback_text', 'ratings', and 'location'. I will add the sample data above.

Comment: Yes but apperantly it wasn't directly assigned from `pd.read_csv` or something; I meant how is the variable defined in the code with `data1 = ...` or similar.

Comment: dataset=pd.read_sql_query(sql, db)
data1=pd.DataFrame(dataset)

Comment: Yes, it is. After reading from the sql query, it has been converted to a dataframe.

Comment: Interesting; `pd.DataFrame` should be making a copy anyway but still you can try `data1 = pd.DataFrame(dataset).copy()`.

Comment: Just tried. It is still giving the same result (empty dictionary).

Comment: Is the `SettingWithCopyWarning` gone?

Comment: No, still there.

Comment: When I used .loc function as mentioned above, the ```SettingWithCopyWarning``` was gone but the output was still not there.

Comment: About the empty output: I don't know how that dictionary is generated you didn't share that. I also don't know what `tokenizer` is supposed to do. If you can share the data as text, `tokenizer`'s result, how that dictionary is obtained and what should be the desired result, perhaps people can help. I think the main issue here was the `SettingWithCopyWarning` so you might as well ask a new question for the technical part about language processing. I lack the knowledge of those things so I cannot be of help, sorry. (I came for the warning)

Comment: Okay, no problem. Actually, the program is logically correct and it is also giving the result in python console but gets stuck when it is run on Django env which I think is possibly due to the warnings. 
Anyway, thank you for your time and help.